# Is there any way to check, where a PHP constant has been defined?

Tags: php

Everyone says about how to define a constant in PHP or how to check, if it is already defined.

But, is there any way or method for checking, **where** it is defined?

**EDIT**: *I'm asking, about **where** a constant is defined! Where -- that means line of code or file -- not **if** it is defined. So, please, read with understanding and don't give me `get_defined_constants(true)` answers. This function only shows, **if constant was defined** and **whether it is a core-level or user-defined constant**. It does not provide any information (like in case of exception and stack trace), where (line, file) constant was previously defined. Thank you.*

Comment: Your IDE may provide a method to "find in all files". Either that or you can grep the contents of your project folders.

Comment: I think he means what line of the code.

Comment: No problematically u can't see where its defined. U can use the IDE to see u can only see if its defined using !defined('constant')

Comment: Actually, from memory, when you try to REDFINE it, it will warning out and tell you where it was already defined... perhaps there is a trick we aren't aware of?

Comment: `Ctrl + F` or `CMD + F` or `Ctrl + Shift + F` or similar in your IDE xD

Comment: Also as a good programming structure u may define all your constant in a single config file and load it. So u know where it is defined.

Comment: @Fluffeh Either I'm blind or in my case PHP shows the file and line, where a constant is **redefined**, not where it is defined for the first time. I tried this trick before posting this question.

Comment: @trejder Ahh sorry, didn't write out code to test it - just remembered something with line numbers in the warnings. Was hoping there might be a trick there for you to leverage.